# Building OsiriX on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: build, compilation, osx-lion, dicom

> Ld build/Development/Decompress normal i386
>      cd /Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix
>      setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
>
> > /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -L/Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix/build/Development -LBinaries/LibTiff -L/Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix/Binaries -L/Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix/Binaries/Ming "-L/Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix/Binaries/KDU SDK" -L/Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix/Binaries/CharLS -L/Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix/Binaries/VTKLibs -F/Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix/build/Development -F/Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix -filelist /Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix/build/OsiriX_Lion.build/Development/Decompress.build/Objects-normal/i386/Decompress.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -framework Foundation -framework AppKit -framework Foundation -framework Cocoa -framework QuickTime -framework IOKit -lz "-lDCM StaticLibrary" -framework Accelerate -framework QTKit -framework WebKit -lPapyrusToolkit -lfreetypeOsiriX -lgifOsiriX -lmingOsiriX -lpng12OsiriX -lkdu_v64R -framework Quartz -lCharLS -lvtkzlib -o /Users/icthealth/Desktop/dcmtk/osirix/osirix/build/Development/Decompress
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     ".objc_class_name_DCMPix", referenced from:
>         pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in Decompress.o
>        (maybe you meant: .objc_class_name_DCMPixelDataAttribute)
>     "_PapyrusLockFunction", referenced from:
>         _ExtractJPEG2000 in libPapyrusToolkit.a(PapyRead3.o)
>         _ExtractJPEGLS in libPapyrusToolkit.a(PapyRead3.o)
>         _ExtractJPEGlossy16 in libPapyrusToolkit.a(PapyJpeg16.o)
>         _ExtractJPEGlossy12 in libPapyrusToolkit.a(PapyJpeg12.o)
>         _ExtractJPEGlossy8 in libPapyrusToolkit.a(PapyJpeg8.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

While building after creating the Development Scheme for Mac OS X Lion 10.7, the above build errors are generated. Any clues how I can compile OsiriX on Mac OS X Lion 10.7?

Comment: You'll want to ask Osirix support, but it looks like it's a dependencies problem

Comment: Could you give me an idea what exactly you meant by dependencies problem? And Posting on OsiriX support on yahoo! groups doesnt give me any answers...yet.

Comment: There seems to be nothing under the dependencies group...while checking that out in Xcode. And also, after some googling, as they say , this should be a missing frameworks issue. I am currently trying to add some frameworks...

Comment: Yes dependencies problem means a missing framework, but can't be sure.

Comment: Could you give me the steps followed in compilation, if you have done it already, or help me with some links, describing steps taken to compile OsiriX on Mac OS X 10.7.4? I have googled a bit and those steps dont seem to work out, as I always get build errors... Should I start a new thread with this question instead?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't done it myself; a new question would be unlikely to be answered. Edit your question to add details about what you've tried, what frameworks you have installed, etc.

Comment: ps where's your message on Osirix-dev?

Comment: Not sure if this is where I had to put the question. But here goes... Question on OsiriX Yahoo! group :-http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/osirix/message/25466

Comment: Okay I think I should have posted it in Osirix-dev. Just discovered.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your time. I got it to compile finally. The automatic "Validation of project settings" by Xcode 4.3.2 may have caused the problem. This time I didn't try to change any scheme. Just unzipped the binaries and Osirix as target on the next step. Thank you for your time again.

Comment: Great, can you add it as an answer so it's easier for future users to spot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this answer doesn't seem conclusive, I would like to mention what worked and what didn't. Before that, I am using Xcode version 4.3.2 and Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4. I downloaded the source code zip file for OsiriX.

1. Select "Unzip Binaries" and My Mac 32-bit as the target scheme first, and build and run. (This one was always successful).
2. Select "Osirix" and My Mac 32-bit as the next target scheme and, in this version of Xcode it says "Validate Project Settings", as it seemed to be necessary to update the compiler from llvmgcc42 to Apple LLVM, and change the Base SDK to latest Mac OS X (10.7) from the current 10.6 version.

When this change was performed, it threw up varieties of build errors, like the one on my original question, and Apple Mach-O linker error, CLang error, exited with code 1. and so on.

The successful compilation of Osirix in my opinion depends on keeping the old compiler and not updating to latest project settings.